# Not wrapping css div with field_with_errors for fields created with f.text_field but works for f.input

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, view, simple-form, zurb-foundation

I'm having problems with my views.  I'm using zurb foundation for stylesheets and when I enter wrong input in forms I get the error above the form but the fields containing the errors are not wrapped with red.  Looking further into this there is no field_with_errors div wrapper for the input fields.  After looking further into this I found out if I use f.input instead of f.text_field I get the correct error wrapping.

As zurb has styles for text_field, text_area etc. I'm using those but I don't get the error div from rails.  Is there any good solution to this?

Here I get correct Zurb foundation styling but no field_with_errors div:

```
.field
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name, :class => "input-text"
```

Here I don't get the Zurb styling but the element is wrapped with field_with_errors div:

```
.field
  = f.label :name
  = f.input :name, :class => "input-text"
```

So basicly it seems the f.text_field helper somehow bypasses the Rails view mechanism of providing div classes to show the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass `class` to SimpleForm's input you should use

```
= f.input :name, :input_html => { :class => 'input-text' }
```

Answer (score 1):

`f.text_field` is the Rails form helper, not simple_form's helper (Since you tagged this with simple-form, I'll assume you are using that). Since simple form only wraps its own attributes with errors, it is ignoring the rails form helper attributes.

What you probably want is

```
= f.input :name, :as => :string
```

You also don't need your own label with simple_form either, so we can condense `f.label` and `f.text_field` to become:

```
= f.input :name, :as => :string, :label => "Custom label"
```

If you leave off the :label attribute, it will default to the name of the symbol, in this case your label will be "Name". With the :label attribute gives you a label titled "Custom Label".

Hope that helps.