# simple_form Bootstrap error validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

In the rails tutorial chap 7, Listing 20,
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-signup_error_messages M. Hartl used a class

```
field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
  .form-control {
    color: $state-danger-text;
  }
```

to style input errors highlighting with bootstrap. Here he is using form_for helper.
I am trying to do the same thing with simple_form but it is not working. Anyone knows how to solve this? I want to highlight my simple_form input field when there is an error.
Please note that i m using f.input_filed

```
 <div class="input-group sign_up">
     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-asterisk fa-2x"></i></span>
     <%= f.input_field :password_confirmation, label: false, placeholder: "Confirm password", class: "form-control input-lg" %>   
    </div>

   <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></span>
    <%= f.input_field :email, label: false, placeholder: "Email", class: "form-control input-lg" %>   
   </div>
    <div class="form-group margin-btn_top">
   <%=f.button :submit, 'Create my account', class:  "btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg", id: "btn-signup" %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: try `:error => true` to your field, `.field_with_errors
  input
    border: 2px solid red` soemthing like this should work

Answer (score 0):

1. First see a mistake in css code

   ```
       field_with_errors {
         @extend .has-error;
         .form-control {
           color: $state-danger-text;
         }
   ```

to

```
.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
  .form-control {
    color: $state-danger-text;
  }
```

2. Also, to display the block of errors you can do something like shown below

   ```
   <% if @YOUR_VARIABLE.errors.any? %>
     <div id="error_explanation">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        The form contains <%= pluralize(@YOUR_VARIABLE.errors.count,"error")%>.
      </div>
      <ul>
       <% @YOUR_VARIABLE.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
         <li><%= msg %></li>
       <% end %>
       </ul>
     </div>
   <% end %>
   ```

**UPDATE**

*With*
([Not wrapping css div with field_with_errors for fields created with f.text_field but works for f.input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188845/not-wrapping-css-div-with-field-with-errors-for-fields-created-with-f-text-field))

If you want to pass class to SimpleForm's input you should use

```
= f.input :name, :input_html => { :class => 'input-text' }
```

Comment: Everything i did, it just what you posted here. But somehow I dont see the results I was expecting. Do i have to add the class .field_with-errors somewhere?

Comment: The .field_with_errors automatically generated. 
(http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views) Displaying Validation Errors in Views.
show us the complete code used to try to further help.

Comment: If i use f.input my custom stilling goes away. any other to work this arround?

Comment: <div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12"><%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %><%= render 'shared/error_messages' %><div class="input-group sign_up "><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i></span><%= f.input_field :name, label: false, placeholder: "Username", class: "form-control input-lg" %>  </div><div class="input-group sign_up"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-asterisk fa-2x"></i></span><%= f.input_field :password, label: false, placeholder: "Password", class: "form-control input-lg" %>  </div>

Comment: <div class="form-group margin-btn_top"><%=f.button :submit, 'Create my account', class:  "btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg", id: "btn-signup" %> </div><% end %></div>
I really new, dont know how the code formatting works in  a comment. Sorry for the inconvenience